# If select option value matches text in separate div, add disabled field

Tags: javascript

I'm using a select field on my site which reloads the page and then adds this to value to a separate div. I want to be able to disable this option if any of the divs have the same value as the option.

```
 <select id="bayname" name="bayname">                      
              <option value="">--Select Bay--</option>
              <option value="1">Bay 1</option>
              <option value="2">Bay 2</option>
              <option value="3">Bay 3</option>
              <option value="4">Bay 4</option>
              <option value="5">Bay 5</option>
              <option value="6">Bay 6</option>
              <option value="7">Bay 7</option>
              <option value="8">Bay 8</option>
              <option value="9">Bay 9</option>
              <option value="10">Bay 10</option>
              <option value="11">Bay 11</option>
              <option value="12">Bay 12</option>
              <option value="13">Bay 13</option>
              <option value="14">Bay 14</option>
              <option value="15">Bay 15</option>
              <option value="16">Bay 16</option>
              <option value="17">Bay 17</option>
              <option value="18">Bay 18</option>
              <option value="19">Bay 19</option>
              <option value="20">Bay 20</option>
              <option value="21">Bay 21</option>
              <option value="22">Bay 22</option>
              <option value="23">Bay 23</option>
              <option value="24">Bay 24</option>
              <option value="25">Bay 25</option>
              <option value="26">Bay 26</option>
              <option value="27">Bay 27</option>
              <option value="28">Bay 28</option>
              <option value="29">Bay 29</option>
              <option value="30">Bay 30</option>
            </select>
```

For example if a user clicks on 'Bay 1' a div will be created like this:

```
<li id="1509013949" class="cart-select cart-mode-cart">
<a href="#select" target="1509013949" onclick="return BMCWcMs.command('select', this);" title="Select Cart">1</a>
</li>
```

And then when the page reloads again, i want to create an if statement so if the value from the select is within one of the divs then it should add it as disabled.

I've had ago at doing this using the code below and i can't get it to print out in the console log.

```
var baynumberoption = $("#bayname option").val();
var baynumber = $(".cart-select a[href='#select']").text();

if (baynumber.indexOf(baynumberoption) >= 0) {
     console.log("match found");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#bayname option")` returns all of the options so I think you really want to use the following.  Note if you don't want to rely on the inner text of the link, you can also add data attribute like `data-id="1"` to store the value which can be used like:

```
$("#bayname option").each(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   if ( $(".cart-select a[data-id=" + val + "]").length > 0 ) {
      $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");  
   }
});
```

Some of the syntax may be off but you get the idea.